# 404 Error reaching the Node.js server at "nodejs/health/check"

Tags: node.js, drupal-7

I'm using a nodejs module on a Drupal 7 website. Here's the message I'm getting in the log on random pages:

Message Error reaching the Node.js server at "nodejs/health/check": [404] Not Found.

Tried restarting Nodejs but it appears to be already running. So why this error?

Comment: The route `nodejs/health/check` does not exist. The server is returning a 404. Please provide your code (routes) and full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks Dannypaz.  How would I do that?

Comment: i suspect it s about this module https://github.com/beejeebus/drupal-nodejs. I found a similar q at https://www.drupal.org/node/2042677. I d like to ask configuration files and so on.

Answer (score 3):

How are you restarting your node server. From the terminal wherever you start the server you'll get your stack trace. 
or if it returns the error you may simply see it on your browser screen from where the request originated.

The terminal is that black screen where you type things in linux and Osx something akin to the command prompt of window . 
[image: Stack Trace in Browser Window]

Is it a get or a post request. 
Are you using express . I assume you are . 
Look for file app,js or routes.js where you may  have code like  :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();`
router.post('/user/', controllers.users.create); //This is a route
```

---

You would have a file in your node directory like app.js

You must have a route defined been like :

**`router.<method>('<route>',<function(req, res, next){}> ) ;`**

So if its a get request , with the route being "nodejs/health/check"  , and some function that acts as your api endpoint : You should have a line like :

```
router.get('nodejs/health/check', checkHealth(req, res){
 console.log("output something");
 res.send("Outputed Something")
} ) ;
```

Where

- > router is the instance of the express object.
- > checkHealth is the function endpoint as you have defined in line as shown
  >   above or in another controller file .

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your route does not exist. To create a route, you will do something like:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/nodejs/health/check', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('theHTMLPage', {foo:bar}); //in the {}, you will be passing params the html page might need if it using a template engine
})
```

or

```
router.get('/nodejs/health/check', function(req, res, next){
    res.send('Whatever you want to send back');
})
```

res.render tells node to go to this other URL and pass on the params in the {}
res.send just passes some info back like: 'Whatever you want to send back' in the example above